# select like but as the whole string between delimiter

Tags: php, mysql

column `tags`:

```
sky***earth***moon  
sun***animals***iron  
silver***gold***night
```

`***` - is delimiter for different tags

I want to search that column by string `anima`

```
$sql = "select * from images where tags like '%anima%'";
```

It gives me `animals` in result, but I need just `anima` as the whole string, delimited by `***`.

In the above example result should be zero.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REGEXP` and search for `anima` surrounded by word boundaries:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]anima[[:>:]]';
```

Follow the link below for a demo which shows that the logic is correct.

### Demo

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

> REGEXP and RLIKE are synonyms for REGEXP_LIKE().

So we also could have used `RLIKE` instead of `REGEXP`.

Comment: Could you write your regexp using `$_POST['abc']` instead of `anima`, pls?

Comment: @puerto I can't, because my PHP is weak, and I don't know which PHP framework you are using.  But the above query is probably the way to go here.  I will add a demo now.

Comment: there is no any framework, `$_POST` is a common variable in php. My `regexp` is very weak, by I will try, anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Play around with the demo until you feel comfortable enough using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below also

```
SELECT * FROM `test_user` WHERE name RLIKE "[[:<:]]anima[[:>:]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Tim Biegeleisen answer, just to show how to add in the php.  Please keep in mind that you should be using parameterized queries which this example is not.

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$_POST['abc']}[[:>:]]'";
```

Comment: Just to illustrate how to add in the post value. The parameterized query is an entire other topic.